# mootools doing POST shows as OPTIONS in firebug

Tags: forms, ssl, post, mootools

I am sending a request using post, but on firebug I see the request type is OPTIONS.
How do I avoid that?
Here is the code I am using:

```
var Req = new Request.HTML({'onSuccess':function(responseTree){
                                                        $('my_id').innerHTML='';
                        $('my_id').adopt(responseTree);
     },'url':'/home/takecare.php'}).post($('Form-id'));
```

I am using SSL (i.e. the url is https://somthing.com/v.php)

Comment: huh? the request class supports method: so you'd do: new Request({method: "post"}); but post is the default... can you post a screenshot of the capture or something?

Comment: are you doing cross domain or non ssl to ssl (or vice versa)? also, OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0 requests are kind of supplementary to main requests and not exchangable (i.e. can't use method OPTIONS). do look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html for clues as to why it would need them, perhaps the header is incomplete and needs some changes

Comment: Thanks - you gave me the right direction to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  Dimitar Christoff implied, the error was due to submission from https url to http.
Changing that fixed the problem.